# querying across application insights resource with REST API

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have data which are stored in 3 different application insights resources, thanks to `query across resource` feature added last year (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/query-across-resources/) was possible to query those 3 application insights at once with `app` identifier.

I'm trying to execute this query through `app insights REST API` : https://dev.applicationinsights.io (app insights REST API) for a very basic need from a static HTML page (no backend)

but without luck
[image]

I do suspect that `app` identifier isn't supported, it is actually the case ? any workaround for my use case (no backend).

Comment: i'm not sure you can do it in the api explorer, since you need to provide the api keys for *ALL* the resources to do a cross app query when using api keys, and i'm not sure the tester lets you do that?  I've forwarded this on to the team that owns it though to verify.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm suspecting. thanks for forwarding & glad if you can confirm/undermine (I have an easy workaround, but always happy to learn new approaches that could be useful in the future :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with the dev team that owns that service:

You should be able to put the api key in as `apiKey1:appId1,apiKey2:appId2` in the api key box and this should work.

the `[object ProgressEvent]` response is a bug in the explorer that should have really showed you an error.

And as a workaround, you could always do the queries inside the azure portal itself in workbooks for any of the AI resources, or hypothetically also from the analytics portal for any of the AI resources, and those wouldn't require the API key at all, if all you needed was to see the data.

Comment: lol, this *should* work but is also broken until they fix it in the explorer.  added workarounds of other ways to retrieve this data (workbooks, analytics portal)

Comment: I would perform a test directly from postman so explorer shouldn't be an issue. however, REST API requires both Application Id & ApiKey. Not clear for me about several application Ids. 
For Apikey, how does it relates app('system1') -> system1:apikey1 ?
thanks for the ideas of workaround as well :)

Comment: you'd end up with a header like `x-api-key: apiKey1:appId1,apiKey2:appId2` I believe you can also use appId's in the `app(x)` syntax in the query too, instead of app names.

Comment: my wondering was about the endpoint url as it's referring to an appId, : https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/[appId]/query. however with one appId in my 3 ones + using apiKey1:appIdGuid1,apiKey2:appIdGuid2 + app('appIdGuid1') (not with name) I was able to make it works.

Comment: Has this changed? I'm facing the same problem and the suggested solution isn't working for me (not in the API explorer, nor using Postman or similar).

Comment: According to the documentation https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Cross-Resource-Queries one should be able to pass in the apps to query in the body, but that gives me insufficient access errors. The example in the docs uses a bearer token, but also says that using API keys is recommended over the oauth flow. IF cross resource queries are only supported when using bearer tokens the documentation should be more clear about that. The REST API is very important, as the dashboard is very limited (and many other reasons).

Comment: After reading your answer and the comments a few times I finally got it working. I'll post an example for the next person :) I'd like to add to the documentation (examples and text)- are the docs open source and open for pull requests?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with the query in the body. My queries are quite complex and have a lot of let statements and therefore passing the query in the body is easier. There are some PowerShell quirks in the example below, but I'll update with a C# example tomorrow.

The let statement in the example below is pretty pointless, it's mostly there to show that you can do complex queries with let expressions etc.

AppId is the Application Insights resource ID - and NOT the instrumentation key. The API key is just a long string and you can create up to 10 of them AFAIK.

You will find both the id and keys under API Access (I've added a screenshot as it's easy to get them confused). When you use the app() function use the app id.

[image]

```powershell
$app1Id = "GUID"
$app2Id = "GUID"

$app1Key = "string"
$app2Key = "string"

# EXAMPLE: "X-Api-Key" = "key1:GUID1,key2:GUID2"
$headers = @{ "X-Api-Key" = "${app1Key}:$app1Id,${app2Key}:$app2Id"; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }

# EXAMPLE: "query" = "union app('GUID1').something, app('GUID2').something | limit 5"
$query = @{"query" = "let days=1d;union app('$app1Id').exceptions,app('$app2Id').exceptions | where timestamp > ago(days)"}
$body = ConvertTo-Json $query | % { [regex]::Unescape($_) }

$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$app1Id/query" -H $headers -Body $body -Method POST
```

The query above will return all the exceptions for the two Application insights resources for the last day. You can do a query across 10 resources at the time of writing, 200 requests per 30 seconds or a max of 86,400 requests per day (UTC). Other limits apply if you use ADD.

NOTE: the extra {} in the header is a **PowerShell quirk** in regards to variables and the use of the colon char, and as you can see in the example **you should not bracket the keys in the header :)**