# Querying multiple application insights resources with REST API

Tags: azure, rest, appinsights

I'm trying to query two different **application insight** instances (instance A and B) trough the **REST API**. I'm using postman to send a GET http request to the API  and followed the answer in this post, which was aiming towards the same goal, join request data from different applications insights: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248597/17161618

Just as it says in the above mentioned post I'm acessing the instance A and passed the authentication through the request header in the format keyA:appIdA,KeyB:appIdB.

I'm sending the following query:" union app("AppIdA").traces,app("AppIdB").traces " and receive the following error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgIgC.png)

Does anyone know how can I get access to read logs in resource B ?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run cross-component queries using API keys. You should use AAD (Azure Active Directory) auth. Give AAD app access to both resources. Then you should be able to run such queries.